# Will it work to sort an array in O(n) when half array is smaller than the other?

Tags: sorting, runtime

Let's say the comparison of elements in array takes O(n), is it possible to sort the array in O(n) when the first half elements of the array is smaller than the other half?

I think yes this would make it even easier to sort because elements arent mixed that much. So we take care of the first half, the smaller one,
just compare one element with another and sort. Then do same with the second half. Wouldn't this work in O(n)?

Comment: When you mean the first half is smaller than the other half, do you mean that all elements are less than what's in the second half? Are these elements already sorted themselves, or just randomly distributed? IOW: is it like this: {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 400, 100, 200, 500, 300} or like this: {5, 2, 1, 4, 3, 400, 100, 200, 500, 300} ? If it's like the second then I would suspect there is no benefit to sort time.

Comment: @blahfunk:
Yes all elements are less than what's in the second half. No the elements aren't sorted themselves. If they were then all elements would be sorted from begin to end, right? :D

Comment: You could _possibly_ optimize it (but not necessarily) if you knew it was going to be split down the middle at the time of programming. But it would likely be an anti-optimization to try to do anything about it at runtime. So, this seems XY Problem-ish. It also depends on factors like the sorting algorithm you use, or if you are sorting into a new container (which isn't exactly _sorting_ but could benefit).

Answer (score 0):

So you're splitting the array into two pieces, with all the items in the first piece less than the smallest item in the second piece. Then you sort the individual pieces? That sounds suspiciously like how [Quicksort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort) works.

And, no, you can't in general sort an array in O(n). It's long been known that the lower bound on comparison sorting is O(n log n). See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_sort#Number_of_comparisons_required_to_sort_a_list for a quick overview of why. You can get detailed references from there.

Answer (score 0):

I do not get this statement :

> Let's say the comparison of elements in array takes O(n)

Leaving that statement : No, it is not O(n). You can do as you mentioned but we are not given any information about elements in both the halves. So, to sort the first half you need (n/2).log(n/2) time and similarly for second half you need (n/2).log(n/2) time. So for the whole array you need n.log(n/2) which is O(nlogn).